# Meteor: There is no route for the path error. how to access SINGLE article within a nested object

Tags: meteor, multidimensional-array, meteor-blaze, flow-router, mongo-collection

I have an array of 10 objects 'categories' and each category has sub objects such as posts within that category. This is how it looks.

[image]

I access the category list like this.

```
<template name="CategoriesMain">
  {{#each articles}}
    <li>
      <a href="/unfiltered/{{_id}}"><h2>{{name}}</h2></a>
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
</template>
```

this link

```
<a href="/unfiltered/{{_id}}"><h2>{{name}}</h2></a>
```

accesses the 'posts' list within the category which looks like this

```
<template name="CategoriesSingle">

<h1>This is a test</h1>
<ul>
  {{#each articles}}
  {{#each posts}}
    <li>
      <a href="/catsingle/{{_id}}"><h2>{{title}}</h2></a>
    </li>
    {{/each}}
  {{/each}}
</ul>
</template>
```

this link is supposed to target the SINGLE POST from the post list within the category

```
<a href="/catsingle/{{_id}}"><h2>{{title}}</h2></a>
```

PROBLEM:

I get the error: There is no route for the path: /catsingle/ when ever i try to access the SINGLE POST

even though i have it in my routes.js like this

```
FlowRouter.route('/catsingle/:_id', {
    name: 'catsingle',
    action() {
        BlazeLayout.render("AppLayout", {main: "CategoryArticleSingle"});
    }
});
```

the template helper looks like this

```
  Template.CategoryArticleSingle.helpers({
      articles: function () {
        var id = FlowRouter.getParam('_id')
        return CategoryCollection.findOne({_id: id});
      }
    });
```

How can I successfully the single post within a category?

Answer (score 0):

Your `posts` array doesn't have an `_id` key, it has an `ID` key.

Try:

```
<a href="/catsingle/{{ID}}"><h2>{{title}}</h2></a>
```

Comment: I did this, the route is working fine, its going to the template ok, but i can't get the {{title}} to output anything, worse is there are no errors. @MichelFloyd

Comment: i can clearly see the posts in the console.log, but for some reason i can get them in the template

Comment: (1) Make sure that `CategoryCollection.findOne({_id: id})` actually returns something. (2) If you are looking at just a single document you want `{{#with articles}}` instead of `{{#each articles}}` because the latter expects a cursor (i.e. the result of a `.find()`) instead of a single document (a `.findOne()`)

Comment: yes you where right, it wasn't returning anything, i found out that i needed to iterate through the array to get to the object i need so i used underscore findWhere. it works well in the console but when i try it in my app, it won't do.. i posted the question with all the code i used here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37931938/meteor-underscore-findwhere-iteration-through-loop-objects-only-works-in-chrom    please take a look if you can. your help is always aprecieted. @MichelFloyd